# Opencart Order Staus Id?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I am using opencart 2.2 and All my orders get's status 0 in DB order_status_id = 0

can some one hellp me?

Regards,
Karolis

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings --> Complete Order Status` and change it to which status you would like the order to default to when an order is completed. Then only when a successful order is placed it would default to the order status you specified as above.